# how to solve problem with create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch 
https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fscope-manager: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nurlan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-17T07_07_31_258Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a slow connection. Try increasing the timeout from 30s to 60s by adding this to your `.npmrc` file:

```
timeout=60000
```

You could also try adding

```
prefer-offline=true
```

if you are trying to save bandwidth or have a slow connection

Note: if you don't have an `.npmrc` file setup yet, you can create one here

- for Windows: `C:\Users\{username}\.npmrc`
- for Mac/Linux `~/.npmrc`

Or you can create one in the same directory as your project's `package.json` file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).